# Intellij IDEA Hotswap for .xhtml files with WebLogic

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, primefaces, hotswap, hotdeploy

I have been working to find out this problem however with no success. I have a project that uses primefaces and .xhtmls, .javas etc. I am using Weblogic server in Intellij IDEA. I am trying to see changes from my browser when I change the .xhtml file and use "update classes and resources". However, I am not successful for that.  By the way, this works when I changed the .java file. For .xhtml file there is no success.

PS: I use exploded artifact for that.

PS2: When I use "Update classes and resources" button, I see that ear is updated from windows explorer.

PS3: I used On 'Update' action with 'Update classes and resources' option, I used On frame deactivation with 'Update classes and resources' option and with different options, but no, nothing, no success.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar setup and this works for me:

1. Deploying an exploded artifact;
2. Exploded artifact should be build on make (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>) - go to File > Project Structure > Artifacts and check "Build on make";
3. Build/make with IDE compiler (e.g not with maven) in order the IDE to understand that there is a changed file and to replace it.

The above is enough to update the xhtmls on every build/make of the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), I do not use "Update classes and resources" neither manually nor automatically (e.g on frame deactivation)

Comment: are you using war or ear?

Comment: You have a solution for a ear structure ?

Answer (score 0):

To update resources on your server you need to press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was to check "Unpack nested archives" of the .ear in the File->Project Structure:
[image]